# Need to replace data in a found string with null

Tags: mysql

Please forgive me If I am asking a very basic question here. What I am needing to do is update the query below so that when It pulls `insurance.insuranceName`, it will replace "Non Medicare " with "". The current query is pulling the insurance ID verifying if it is 0 then returning 'Self Pay' otherwise it is returning the insID's name.

This causes some issues with data validation, which I have no control over, where they see the word Medicare and assume that it is a Medicare plan. I would like to remove "Non Medicare" from the returned insurance name and return the rest.

Current query:

```
/*Pulling Primary Insurance Name and setting any data with a '0' as self-pay*/
IF(edi_invoice.PrimaryInsId = 0, 'Self-Pay', (SELECT insurance.insuranceName FROM insurance 
                                              WHERE insID = edi_invoice.PrimaryInsid AND edi_invoice.PrimaryInsid <> 0)) AS prim_payer_name,
```

I have tried different placements for the replace command, just not sure where I am needing it to go or if there is a better function for what I am needing to do. This is a data extraction not a situation where I would want the entries changed in the database. just to be clear.

With the current query, I get the following output:

- MEDICARE - ASC
- BCBS - ASC
- UHC Non Medicare Adv UB
- HEALTHCHOICE

The desired output would be:

- MEDICARE - ASC
- BCBS - ASC
- UHC Adv UB
- HEALTHCHOICE

Comment: Dang hes fast, yeah just use the Replace command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT REPLACE(insurance.insuranceName, 'Non Medicare', '') as insuranceName
FROM insurance 
WHERE insID = edi_invoice.PrimaryInsid 
AND edi_invoice.PrimaryInsid <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to place that in the correct location to get it to work as expected:
IF(edi_invoice.PrimaryInsId = 0, 'Self-Pay',
 (SELECT REPLACE(insurance.insuranceName, "Non Medicare ","")
 FROM insurance 
 WHERE insID = edi_invoice.PrimaryInsid AND edi_invoice.PrimaryInsid <> 0))
 AS prim_payer_name,